# How to throw an error in SSDT Post-Deploy script to fail it's execution?

Tags: sqlcmd, ssdt, deployment, raiserror

I'm using Microsoft SSDT to version DB schema. I have a script to autogenerate some triggers and i need to make sure that we don't forget to run it when tables change. I added a part to PostDeploy script, which takes pristine trigger definitions, compares them to existing ones and raises error if they don't match, but the error doesn't abort PostDeploy script, I don't even see it or preceeding `PRINT` message (I even tried throwing error at the beginning of script). I suspect this is because script runs in SQLCMD mode. Is there any way I can force this script to fail and attract users attention to the reason?